# How do I redirect command output to vim in bash?

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I am trying to redirect the output of a bash command into a new file.

If I try the pipe as below :

```
ls -la | vim
```

Bash shows me the errors :

```
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

I know that I can open Vim and then use :

```
:r !ls -la
```

But is there a way to do this in bash itself, so that Vim is opened and the output is pasted there automatically?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (this also works with applications that can't read from `STDIN`):

```
vim <(ls -la)
```

Or use `vim`'s function to read from `STDIN`:

```
ls -la | vim -
```

Comment: `<(ls -la)` is actually [process substitution](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) rather than [command substitution](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: I really like vim's option, it allows me to search, find and save the output easily from data dumps.

Comment: vim will warn of your buffer is not saved. You may pass `-R` or `-c "setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile"` to avoid this.

Comment: This question/answer is the closest to what I've been trying to search on SO, but if anyone can help me: Is it possible to be using a shell (ie bash), and then turn my current shell buffer (ie, everything above my cursor) into a doc I can temp edit in vim? Even read only? For example `ls somdir/` and then after it dumps output, i can search and yank from it? Much appreciated!!!

Comment: @EvanMorrison This is a good question, why not [asking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) it?

Comment: @chaos Thanks, [I did](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311906/using-terminal-buffer-as-context-for-vim):)

Comment: @EvanMorrison I know that hitting `v` while typing a command in bash brings up the command in `vim`. But just the command...

Comment: Entering the command `ls -la | vim` in bash results in `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal` and `vim` just exits. But `vim <(ls -la)` works for me As does its `gvim` analog.

Comment: @TomRussell You need the `-` (minus) after the command to tell vim to read from the stdin.

Comment: @chaos I see my error. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to make this the default behavior for certain git commands?  I have my .zshrc set up to open man pages in vim by default, for example.

Answer (score 59):

You're really close on your own.  You were just missing one character.

```
ls -la | vim -
```

Comment: Well technically it's two characters. ;)

Comment: Clean and elegant. Thank you

Answer (score 25):

Here's another approach, hopefully to teach someone something new.

If you know that the command `:r !ls -la` works inside vim, you can do the following to open vim and make it run the command as soon as it opens, straight from bash:

```
vim -c ':r! ls -la'
```

This is the equivalent of opening `vim` then executing the command `:r! ls -la`. This should work with any `vim` command, where the command comes after the `-c` option.

Comment: I like it. This results in a little cleaner launch of `vim` on my system (doesn't hang the `bash` terminal) but results in the output from `git diff` missing syntax highlighting. This may be a particularity of my system.

Comment: I meant, cleaner launch of `gvim`... And `bash` comes back with a carriage return.

Answer (score 15):

You can tell vim to open stdin:

```
ls -la | vim -
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add an option

`ls -al | view -`

`view` is a read-only version of vim(equivalent to `vim -R`)

Answer (score 1):

**`setlocal buftype=nofile`**

This is a good option if you are going to create an alias to replace `less`:

```
seq 100 | vim +':setlocal buftype=nofile' -
```

Now you don't need to type the ! to quit.

Another option is:

```
seq 100 | vim +'nnoremap q :quit!' -
```

so you can exit with just `q<enter>`.

Comment: Good idea. Definitely shorter than typing this long ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to get the output into a text file then you don't need to invoke vim. Bash can do it alone with

```
ls -la > outputfile.txt
```