# Using terminal buffer as context for Vim

Tags: command-line, vim

When using the terminal, I wish I could search through the output from commands and scroll up terminal buffer, in read-only mode, with Vim keybindings.

An example is running `ls -al` and then wanting to capture a single long file name from the output. With Vim, this would be a piece of cake.

I am aware that there are ways to pipe output of a command into Vim. I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: What is your terminal emulator? Gnome-terminal, Xterm, other? See [Is there a way to open screen's terminal scrollback buffer in vim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/402424) for some ideas.

Comment: I am using the ubuntu distro from WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which i typically access via the windows command prompt. It seems like your answers might lead me to a workable solution -- i'll post it here if I get it going :)